# Draggable JQuery UI is slow

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I just started using JQuery UI to create a draggable div.  When the user drags the div, the css of another div on the page changes.  However, I've noticed a huge lag in the dragging when I put in a .css function in the drag function.  Code below:

```
$( "#drag-box" ).bind( "drag", function(event, ui) {
          $(this).stop().css('left',event.offsetX);
          $.carousel.limit = $.carousel.len - $(window).width();
          var margin = $.carousel.currentMargin;
          var ratio = ui.position.left / 200;
          var new_margin = $.carousel.limit * ratio;

          $('#storyboard-container').css({'margin-left': -new_margin + 'px'});
      });
```

The #drag-box lags a lot, especially if a user drags the box really quickly.  Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to add your HTML or better yet a jsFiddle example illustrating the issue.